# Send JSON by ajax and get parameters by request in JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I need to send a JSON object by ajax (with Jquery) and get all parameters by the request Object in JSP (server side).

My JS code is:

```
        var request = new Object();
        request.param1= "value1";
        request.param2 = "value2";
        $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: 'test.jsp',
        //data: {request:JSON.stringify(dataSend)},
        //data: {request:dataSend},
        //data: JSON.stringify(request),
        data:request,
        async:true,
        success:function(r){
            console.log(r);
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

And my JSP code is:

```
<%@page import="cl.test.pos.web.delegate.POSXXXXXXXX"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<% 
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
if(session.getAttribute("role") != null ){
    POSXXXXXXXX bx = new POSXXXXXXXX();
    String je;
    je = bx.setTest(request);
    out.print(je);
    out.close();
}else{
    j.put("responseStatus","EXCEPTION");
    request.getSession().invalidate(); 
    out.print(j);
    out.close();
}
%>
```

And the Method Class is

```
    public String setTest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    try{
        j.putAll(request.getParameterMap());
        j.put("responseStatus", "OK");
    }catch(FrameworkException e){
        /*Any code*/
    }catch(Throwable t){
        /*Any code*/
    }
    return j.toJSONString();
    }
```

I Expect return a JSON Object on client and this is so, but, the response is like this:

> {"param1":[Ljava.lang.String;@182f12f,"param2":[Ljava.lang.String;@1a881f5}

Values are not understandable and if I send Objects and Arrays, it are so wrong too, for example:

> {"parametro4[1][p3]":[Ljava.lang.String;@c5954b,"parametro4[1][p4]":[Ljava.lang.String;@1cc9339,"parametro5[arr1][]":[Ljava.lang.String;@1d5af30}

Please Help me to get All parameters on a JSONObject from HttpServletRequest. I really need to know the best way to do this.

(I already searched in StackOverFlow and the surfing in the web, and I cannot found The best way to do this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved this problem (almost at all), from this way:

```
public String setTest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{
JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
try{
    JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
    Map m = request.getParameterMap();
    Gson gi = new Gson();
    String stringJson = gi.toJson(m);
    j.put("jsonParse",jp.parse(stringJson));
    j.put("responseStatus", "OK");
}catch(FrameworkException e){
    /*Any code*/
}catch(Throwable t){
    /*Any code*/
}
return j.toJSONString();
}
```

and server response correctly (almost):

> {"jsonParse":{"parametro5[arr1][]":["1","2","3"],"pagoAbono":["false"],"parametro4[1][p4]":["3"],"parametro4[1][p3]":["2"],"parametro1":["parametro1"],"parametro4[0][p2]":["1"],"codigoCaja":[""],"parametro5[arr2][1][0][letraX]":["x"],"numeroCheque":[""],"facturasPagos":["195310|234509"],"rutCliente":["154809597"],"banco":[""],"caducidadMes":[""],"parametro4[0][p1]":["0"],"parametro5[arr2][1][]":["x","x"],"numeroTarjeta":[""],"caducidadYear":[""],"montoTotalPago":["334772"],"nombreTitular":[""],"parametro5[arr2][0][]":["a","b","c"],"parametro3[]":["a","b","c"],"parametro2[atributo1]":["atributo1"]},"responseStatus":"OK"}

The only Detail is that the Arrays and Objects are interpreted like the request parameter instead the real Javascript JSONObject.

For example:

If client send this:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.param1 = [1,2,3];
```

Server response this:

```
obj[param1][0]=1;
obj[param1][1]=2;
obj[param1][2]=3;
```

Instead to response:

```
obj.param1[0]=1;
obj.param1[1]=2;
obj.param1[2]=3;
```

I hope you can understand the problem, and give to me a clue or solution.

Answer (score 1):

The **parameterMap** value is an Array Object and not String:

> Returns: an immutable java.util.Map containing parameter names as keys
>   and parameter values as map values. The keys in the parameter map are
>   of type String. **The values in the parameter map are of type String
>   array**.

[javadoc for getParameterMao](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap())

So you will need to code it, just iterate throught the map and put the parameter name/value in the object.